# How do I change my existing EA subscription to EA dev/test

Tags: azure

Currently we have existing Non production workload running running under "EA" subscription. I found microsoft has EA DEV/test subscription offer. Is there a way we can change the existing  subscription offer to "EA dev/test " ?

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, you can convert your existing EA subscription to EA dev/test subscription, for that you will have to sign in as ‘Enterprise Administrator’ in the EA Azure portal and follow the steps as below: -

1. Select Manage on the left navigation.
2. Select the Account tab.
3. Select the row for the account where you would like to enable Dev/Test access.
4. Select the pencil symbol to the right of the row.
5. Select the Dev/Test checkbox.
6. Select Save.

When a user is added as an account owner through the Azure EA Portal, any Azure subscriptions associated with the account owner that are based on either the Pay-As-You-Go Dev/Test offer or the monthly credit offers for Visual Studio subscribers will be converted to the EA Dev/Test offer. Subscriptions based on other offer types, such as Pay-As-You-Go, associated with the Account Owner will be converted to Microsoft Azure Enterprise offers.

For more information, please refer to the below documentation link: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/ea-portal-administration#enterprise-devtest-offer